# Build a html table with input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a html table with two input fields, the first one is composed of 2 images when the user clicked I get 1 or 0 and the second input is a text field.

**feedback.html**

```
<body ng-controller="logFeedbackController">
    <!-- LOG feedback table -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="display table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                        <th>Tags</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="log in logProd">
                        <td>{{ log.message }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div><img src="../../images/buttons/like-icon.png"></div>
                            <div><img src="../../images/buttons/dislike-icon.png"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Tags">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('logAnalysisApp', []);
app.controller('logFeedbackController', function($scope) {
    $scope.logProd = [{
        message : 'test',
    },
    {
        message : 'test2',
    }];
});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('logAnalysisApp',[
    'logFeedbackController'
]);
```

For example if the user like the first message and dislike the second one, I want to retrieve the following json object :

```
'object':{
'0': 
    {
        message : 'test',
        score : 1,
        tags : 'First tags input text values'
    },
'1':
   {
      message : 'test2',
      score : 0,
      tags : 'Second tags input text values '
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new function to your controller `$scope.onClick = function onClick(option) {...}` and then use ngClick https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick to register a click event for that element. You can add `<div ng-click="onClick('like')...` and `<div ng-click="onClick('dislike')....`

For the text input, you need to link it to a model, you can use ngModel for this, check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D . You can add a scope variable `$scope.tags` and then `<input ng-model="tags" ....`.

You should be able to continue from here :) (I hope I understood your question correctly)

Comment: How I can do to retrieve the {{ log.message }} value from the controller ?

Comment: I believe you mean from the HTML (because you have the values in the controller). What you can do, is update onClick function by adding second attribute, e.g `onClick(option, message) ` and `<div ng-click="onClick('like', log.message)"...`

Comment: I added a submit button on the bottom of the table, I want to construct the json object when I click on the submit button

Comment: you can wrap it into a `<form...` and use ngSubmit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit . Idea is, that you define amethod in your controller, you mention it in the form `ng-submit="myOnSubmitMethod()"...`  and then the method will be called when you click the submit button.